# regex select latest file by mask

Tags: regex, bash

I need to select latest build (done) and specific file (in progress)

I have a bash script where I need to select latest build from ftp://buildhub.tideway.com/hub/tkn_main-continuous/publish/tkn/10.2/tku/

Usually, in this directory we have 2 files (in some cases - some older file, so I need to select latest):

```
Technology-Knowledge-Update-2066-08-1-ADDM-10.2+
```

and

```
Technology-Knowledge-Update-Storage-2066-08-1-ADDM-10.2+.zip
```

Among this two files I need to select first (Technology-Knowledge-Update-XXX-XX-X-ADDM-XX.X+.zip. Without "Storage" in filename). And note, that after each build, most digits will change.

Right now I have a bash command, but it does not work:

```
wget -q -O - ftp://buildhub.tideway.com/hub/tkn_main-continuous/publish/tkn/11.0/tku/ | grep -o -m 1 'ftp[^<>]*?.zip' head -1
```

Any ideas how to change regex to select first file?

Comment: `head` should be in a pipeline.

Comment: also, delete `head -1`; `grep -m1` already will return only the first match.

Comment: Ок, I reworked script to:

Comment: `wget -q -O -  ftp://buildhub.tideway.com/hub/tkn_main-continuous/publish/tkn/11.0/tku/ | grep -o -m 1 "([a-zA-Z]{10}[-][a-zA-Z]{9}[-][a-zA-Z]{6}[-])([0-9-]){10}([A-Z]{4})[-]([0-9]\d{1})[.]\d(\+\.zip)"` In regexr editor this expression matched to searched file [link](http://prntscr.com/c7nwfz). But wget didn't return needed file.Anyone can help with it?